# How to add a point in a empty vetorLayer creadted in memory

Tags: qgis, features, c++, api, vector-layer

I am working in c++/qt 4.5 and qgis api c++ 2.8.2
I had to create and empty vectorLayer and add Point
I saw in the qgis cookbook that it is possible to create a vector layer in memory ,I did that, and export to a file I did that too and It Works.

Here is , in detailled step , what I want to do :

a- create a vectorlayer in memory

b- add attributes to it

c- add features to it

d- save it in a shp file to be imported in QGIS

I don't know how to add attribute and set value .

is there a specific procedure ?

do you have somme link or some sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution, perhaps there is other but this one works

first create the layer :

```
qDebug() << "Create Memory Layer Tracks";
QgsVectorLayer * lVectorLayer = new QgsVectorLayer("Point","TRACKS","memory");
lVectorLayer->isValid();
qDebug() << "Vector valid :" << lVectorLayer->isValid();
QgsVectorDataProvider * lDataProvider = lVectorLayer->dataProvider();
// editing mode
lVectorLayer->startEditing();

// add attribute
QList <QgsField> lMyAttribField;
// cerate fields
lMyAttribField  << QgsField("TrackId",QVariant::Int)
    << QgsField("Label",QVariant::String)   
    << QgsField("Type",QVariant::String)    
    << QgsField("Color",QVariant::String)   
    << QgsField("PosX",QVariant::Double)    
    << QgsField("PosY",QVariant::Double)    
    << QgsField("TimeStamp",QVariant::String);  

    lDataProvider->addAttributes(lMyAttribField);
    // save attributes
   lVectorLayer->commitChanges();

    // add to the map
    QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(lVectorLayer);
    // insert the vector layer into the vectorlayermap
    mMapLayer.insert(pType, lVectorLayer);
```

Then you can use it to add feature like this :

```
QgsVectorLayer * lLayer = mMapLayer.value(TRACKS);

if (lLayer == NULL) qDebug() << " lLayer NULL";
else qDebug() << "lLayer Not NULL";

qDebug() << "Vector is Valid ? ::" <<   lLayer->isValid();

QgsVectorDataProvider * lDataProvider;
lDataProvider = lLayer->dataProvider();

//calc random X and Y
PosX =(qrand()%(Xmax-Xmin)+Xmin);
PosY =(qrand()%(Ymin-Ymax)+Ymax);

//create point
QgsGeometry * MyPoint;
MyPoint = QgsGeometry::fromPoint(QgsPoint(PosX,PosY));
QgsFeature MyFeature;
MyFeature.setGeometry(MyPoint);

// set the value
MyFeature.initAttributes(n);
MyFeature.setAttribute(Name,"test");
MyFeature.setAttribute(TrackId , mId) ;
MyFeature.setAttribute(Type , lClassif);
MyFeature.setAttribute(PosY,PosY );
MyFeature.setAttribute(PosX,PosX);
QDateTime MyTime;
MyFeature.setAttribute(Heure , MyTime.currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.zzz"));
MyFeature.setValid(true);

QgsFeatureList MyFeatureList;
MyFeatureList.append(MyFeature);
lDataProvider->addFeatures(MyFeatureList);

lLayer->updateExtents();

// Add the Vector Layer to the Layer Registry
QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(lLayer, TRUE);
// Add the Layer to the Layer Set
QgsMapCanvasLayer PointMapCanvasLayer = QgsMapCanvasLayer(lLayer, TRUE);
mpS57->myListForPrint.insert(1,PointMapCanvasLayer);
// set the canvas to the extent of our layer
mpMapCanvas->setExtent(lLayer->extent());
// Set the Map Canvas Layer Set
mpMapCanvas->setLayerSet(mpS57->myListForPrint);
// zoom full canvas
mpMapCanvas->zoomToFullExtent();
mpMapCanvas->refresh();
mpMapCanvas->updateMap();
mpMapCanvas->updateFullExtent();
```

I hope that this sample help you in the future